# php bootstrap from json file into form and output to json file

Tags: php, json, forms

I feel that I'm nearly there with all the components, I'm just struggling with the assembly!
I'm trying to retrieve data from a json file, then allow the user to edit the data, then send to another file (overwriting this file is not a problem) that json file with the new data. How far away am I? I'll step you through the code:

Variables from the url:

```
  <?php

  echo $_GET['species'];
  echo $_GET['bone'];
  echo $_GET['datasetID'];
```

Get the data from the json file:

```
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("../../json/data.json"), True);
```

Filter the data to get a single record:

```
  function myfilter($row){
    return ($row['datasetID']== $_GET['datasetID']);
  }
  $result = array_filter($data, 'myfilter');
```

Return the data and present it in a bootstrap form:
I expect `foreach` is overkill as only 1 record is returned, is there a return first?

```
  foreach($result as $elem)  {
    echo ("

  <div class='col-12'>
```

Set the method to post, I assume `action` can be `home.php` as a redirect?

```
    <form action='' method='post' class='was-validated'>
      <div class='row'>
```

A few text inputs, the are more, but this'll do for a test case:

```
        <div class='col-2 left'>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='uname'>Data ID:</label>
            <input class='form-control' type='text' value =".$elem['datasetID']." placeholder='".$elem['datasetID']."' readonly>
            <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
            <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class='col-2 left'>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='uname'>Modified:</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' value ='".$elem['modified']."' placeholder='".$elem['modified']."' readonly>
            <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
            <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-2 left'>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='uname'>Language</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' value ='".$elem['language']."' placeholder='".$elem['language']."' >
            <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
            <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='col-2 left'>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='uname'>commonName</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' value ='".$elem['commonName']."' placeholder='".$elem['commonName']."' required>
            <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
            <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
   
        <div class='col-2 left'>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='uname'>elementName</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' value ='".$elem['elementName']."' placeholder='".$elem['elementName']."' >
            <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
            <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='col-2 left'>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='uname'>commonElementName</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' value ='".$elem['commonElementName']."' placeholder='".$elem['commonElementName']."' >
            <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
            <div class='invalid-feedback'>Please fill out this field.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        "
      );
    }
```

End of the foreach loop.

Make a new array, using the `POST` method collect all the keys and submitted data.

```
          $newdata=array();
          foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
              $newdata[$key]=$value;
          }
          $json_a['data'][]=$newdata;

          $json_a=json_encode($json_a);
```

Put the data somewhere

```
          file_put_contents("test.json",$json_a);
```

Complete the form with the submit button and end the html with a final close div.

```
echo"

        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
      </form>
";


    echo '</div>';
  ?>
```

Comment: so whats not working?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: I can see you not added any `name=""` props to your inputs, is that it?

Comment: The above, on submit produces an empty json file, I'll google about the `name` last time I used php it was with databases not json.

Answer (score 0):

Added name element and replaced the php code with:
Please post any improvements.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    function get_data() {
        $datae = array();
        $datae[] = array(
          'type' => $_POST['type'],
          'modified' => $_POST['modified'],
          'language' => $_POST['language'],
           ...

           ...


        );
        return json_encode($datae);
    }
```

Added some internal file arranging code

```
    if (!file_exists("../../json/data/".$_POST['kingdom']."")) {
        mkdir("../../json/data/".$_POST['kingdom']."", 0777, true);
    }
    if (!file_exists("../../json/data/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."")) {
        mkdir("../../json/data/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."", 0777, true);
    }
    if (!file_exists("../../json/data/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."")) {
        mkdir("../../json/data/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."", 0777, true);
    }
    if (!file_exists("../../json/data/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."/".$_POST['order']."")) {
        mkdir("../../json/data/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."/".$_POST['order']."", 0777, true);
    }
    if (!file_exists("../../json/data/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."/".$_POST['order']."/".$_POST['family']."")) {
        mkdir("../../json/data/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."/".$_POST['order']."/".$_POST['family']."", 0777, true);
    }
```

And put the file in the right place

```
    $name = $_POST['genus'];
    $file_name = $name . '.json';

    if(file_put_contents(
        "../../json/data/".$_POST['kingdom']."/".$_POST['phylum']."/".$_POST['class']."/".$_POST['order']."/".$_POST['family']."/$file_name", get_data())) {
            echo $file_name .' file created';
        }
    else {
        echo 'There is some error';
    }
}
```